# NuGet restore force file overwrite

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We recently started building NuGet packages of a project we use in every other of our projects. In this package/project are a lot of content files, like images.
The first time the package gets installed in another project, with the package manager in visual studio 2015, everything works fine.
When we then commit and push the changed project to our remote repository with the content files added in the `.gitignore`, because we don't want all this extra files in the repository.
When we now clone this repository to another computer and try to build it, visual studio restores the NuGet package, but doesn't copy the content files of this package to the project. In the solution explorer the files are all still shown as missing [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyU6H.png).
Is there a way to force an "overwrite" of this in the `csproj` referenced but actually not existing files?
I even tried to do the restore by command line like this

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

Also didn't work, content files are not copied.

Only way to get the content files is to uninstall the package and install it again, then you are prompted if you want to overwrite the existing files. If you answer with yes, the files are copied. But this prompt is not shown with a restore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages restore will only download the NuGet packages and extract them to the packages directory. It will not add the references and content file into project automatically.

So you need to use following command to reinstall the packages in project, which will add references and content files into project.

> Update-Package -reinstall

Comment: so there is really no other way to do this, except a manual reinstall of the package?  i'd really like to have a way to copy the content automatically in visual studio with a restore... :(

Comment: This is the default action for restore packages in NuGet. I help you submit this issue to GitHub: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3787  You could add your comments for this feedback, the NuGet team will treat this issue seriously. But before that, you still need to implement your requirement by using above command to reinstall the packages.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. Thank you.